# There is a way to load main.js last react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to have the main.js last to load. Is there a way to do so in react? In the ComponentDidMount, I placed the main.js second last item but when I did a check on the Chrome Dev Tool, it is the first one to load. Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you try to clear the browser cache once and test again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you are loading the main.js first because it is the only js file appended to the DOM.  Within the js file you are loading in the other scripts.

If you were to hardcode your script tags into your html, you can adjust your load order with that.

Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <script src="/lib/yourotherjsfiles.js"></script>
  <script src="/lib/yourotherjsfiles.js"></script>
  <script src="/lib/yourotherjsfiles.js"></script>
  <script src="/lib/yourotherjsfiles.js"></script>
  <script src="/lib/yourotherjsfiles.js"></script>
  <script src="/lib/yourotherjsfiles.js"></script>
  <script src="/lib/yourotherjsfiles.js"></script>
  <script src="/lib/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi, yes I did indeed use the method you have suggested initially but the wow effect and the isotopes did not work. My page did not have the wow effect and the data filtering using isotopes did not work also. So I ended using componentDidMount to load the javascripts files and it works fine but I needed the main.js to load last. Thanks

Comment: hi, I know what caused it. Apparently, I guessed that js is a reserved word, and having a folder name js would get called first. I placed the main.js in the lib folder and it did get loaded last. Thanks